# Grammar of て + (い)ましょう

Tags: grammar, て-form, volitional-form

How would one explain this -te form of the verb + mashou here:

> **姫, 城の中で隠れてましょうよ**

Does it mean:

1. 隠れて (い)ましょう  [Lets hide and stay] - where the て is used as sequential action

OR

2. 隠れて (い)ましょう [Lets keep hiding] - where its present-progressive-volitional tense

Comment: i understand what you’re asking but is there really a difference between the meaning of those two even in english. it feels a bit hair splitting to me.

Comment: @A.Ellett can both forms be correct ? Cause option 1 has the nuance "to hide" from this point in time and option 2 has the nuance to keep on  "to hide"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only #2. When it appears in the reduced form, it is always an auxiliary (it is less frequently a main verb after a te-form anyways). This is similar to "I'll" or "I don't" cases in English, which are never main verbs in those forms.

> 帰っている = is at home / has been back and stays home
> 帰ってる = is at home

> 書いてしまう = has accidentally written / has written and stores
> 書いちゃう/書いちまう = has accidentally written